# Power Management related to heat

Tags: 16.04, power-management, cpu, process, overheating

What happens to the Ubuntu OS when the hardware gets hot (Process wise)?

Does the OS reduce the numnber of threads? or start to limit processes?

what I have observed (measured) is that when the hardware running ubuntu gets hot, the system runs slower. At some point the OS becomes less responsive, and the efficency drops way down to about 54%. After that, the hardware gets even hotter, and a thermal shut down may occur. Im just wondering what the deafault action is for Ubuntu when the CPU (for instance) gets hot. Is there a process that starts to limit threads, like the OOM Killer?

Answer (score 1):

Install some temperature management software to help monitor/control your temps.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get indicator-sensors
sudo apt-get lm-sensors
sudo apt-get thermald
```

Or use your favorite Software Store or package manager.

You'll want to read up a little on `thermald` by typing `man thermald` and `man thermal-conf.xml`, in `terminal`. After stopping the currently running thermald process, you can run `thermald` manually in `--no-daemon mode` to watch if it's doing the right thing, or as a basis for writing your own custom config file.

You may also wish to blow out any accumulated dust that collects in fans and on the main computer logic board, as this can easily cause heat issues. Lastly, if the machine is kind of old, you may need to re-apply thermal compound between the CPU and the CPU heat pipe/radiator.

Comment: If it's really bad after doing all the things you mentioned, I replace the fan, or even the whole fan aluminum cooling block assembly. Fans are cheap, so if cleaning it doesn't help I replace the fan.

Comment: @karel this may be a laptop, so replacing a fan might be more difficult. But good point.

Comment: I found a computer repair shop where they order the fan for me and also assemble it. Sometimes I have to wait for a while for the parts to arrive at the shop though.